# Role-based Security without Forms Authentication in ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, iprincipal, iidentity

I would like to take advantage of:

```
        Page.User.IsInRole("CustomRole");
        Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

when working inside Page methods, as well as **authorization** section in web.config:

```
<authorization>
    <allow roles="Administrators, Supervisors" />
    <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

and also apply rules on classes and methods level:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Administrators")]
```

In my application I authenticate with ... custom mechanism that provides me user identity in ... http header. I get users PIN number (some kind of ID) + roles. But that is a side plot. It doesn't matter.

What I actually want to achieve is to take advantage of ASP .NET build in Authorization features but having my custom authentication mechanism. I guess I have to implement **IPrincipal** and **IIdentity**, is that right? I saw plenty of samples on the web but all of them include web.config configuration that specifies providers, and also **FormsAuthentication** like classes, that I guess I don't need. I just need to inject my user object (which is prepared by me) into request and that's it.

So:

- what's the easiest way to achieve it?
- what is the difference between GenericPrincipal / IPrincipal?
- how to get/create IIdentity object? I saw samples with:

  var id = new FormsIdentity(authTicket);

but I'm not using FormsAuthentication.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you have to implement your own authentication module.

An authentication module is just an ASP.NET module but having special purpose. Its `AuthenticateRequest` method should populate `HttpContext.Current.User` property with an instance of `IPrincipal`.

Answering your other questions: `IPrincipal` is just an interface while `GenericPrincipal` is one of its implementations. You can use it, as the name suggests it's just a generic implementation which means that it should suit you. Since `IPrincipal` is just `IIdentity` plus roles, you probably will also need `GenericIdentity`.

Other implementations, like `RolePrincipal` + `FormsIdentity` are designed for specific purposes, these two for example are used by the Forms Authentication Module.

There are some good examples available, just google for "custom authentication module".

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible to inject your own IPrinciple when working with Forms Authentication? I tried to use custom authentication, but I have no access to session (I would like to store there my user object, that would be later injected into HttpContext.Current.User), and it's issue for me.

Comment: You can temporarily store your authentication object in the `Items` container and then copy it to session container when session is available (`AcquireRequestState` event).

Answer (score 0):

Before you do (create/implement your own), have you tried/considered adapting Forms Authentication to your existing auth scheme?

I think you're "almost there" (using all of the built-in ASP.net auth/membership/profiles/roles), and it *maybe* easier/simpler to just "plug in" your existing auth scheme into Forms Authentication.

This [snippet of code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx) should give you an idea of how flexible Forms Authentication can be:

```
if ((UserEmail.Text == "jchen@contoso.com") && (UserPass.Text == "37Yj*99Ps"))
{
      FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage 
         (UserEmail.Text, Persist.Checked);
}
else
{ ... }
```

So, it works with a hard coded "auth scheme" (not that you should, but gives you an idea of the possibilities), or even a list [in web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx) - again, just a sample:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".FUBAR">
    <credentials passwordFormat="MD5">
      <user name="foo" password="b7ab5072e8fba7bed20384cc42e96193"/>
      <user name="bar" password="1c42e49a360aa7cc337a268a1446a062"/>
      <user name="john" password="5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99"/>
      <user name="jane" password="7c6a180b36896a0a8c02787eeafb0e4c"/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

Just a thought - hth....

Comment: Everything is fine, but I need to store my own IPrinciple implementation in HttpContext.Current.User. And I don't know whether it's possible with Forms Auth. Thanks!